# Is there a language without compound nouns?

Tags: nouns, linguistic-universals, compounds

The Wikipedia article on [compounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Compound_(linguistics)&oldid=947108700#Noun%E2%80%93noun_compounds) claims:

> All natural languages have compound nouns.

Is there a specific source to back this up? Or are there in fact languages that don't have compound nouns?

If truly all languages have noun-noun compounds, is there an explanation why they are more common than other types of compounds like verb-noun compounds?

I'm not sure where to look for further information. The Wikipedia article itself says that additional citations are needed.

Comment: I suspect it comes down to how you define "compound noun". In a broad sense, the idea that you can build new ways to refer to objects out of existing ways to refer to objects is (generally believed to be) universally true; that comes from the principle of recursion. But that's also not particularly informative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compounding is very rare in Semitic, which appears to contradict the claim.

The following is from Orin D. Gensler, 'Morphological Typology of Semitic', in Stefan Weninger (ed.), *The Semitic Languages: An International Handbook*, pp. 287–288:

> Compounding as such is almost unknown in Semitic. There are of course lexicalized or semi-lexicalized collocational combinations of two nouns, but structurally these are normally indistinguishable from the Head-Genitive syntagm of the Construct (see 5.3.), and the two collocated nouns may be interrupted by the definite article (just as with the Construct). Thus in Arabic we have *ibn al-sabīl* (lit.) ‘son of the road’, i.e.  traveler’, with the article *al-* separating the two combined elements. Only rarely do we find true compounds like Arabic *rās-māl-ī* (lit.) ‘head-capital-Adj’, i.e. ‘capitalist’. In modern (not Biblical) Hebrew, new compounds are not infrequently coined by blending two roots: for example, from *midraḵa* ‘sidewalk’ + *reḥov* ‘street’ the language has created the compound blend *midreḥov* ‘pedestrian mall’ (lit. sidewalk-street). In the modern Ethiosemitic languages ‘compound verb tenses’ are formed, some of which involve the compounding of a verb form and an auxiliary verb, notably ‘to be’; thus in Amharic *təsäbr-alläčč* = ‘she will break’ (lit. she.will.break + she.is)